# List of problem title same style as list of figures title?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I have custom made list of problems, and list of figures generated by `tocloft`. I want the two list titles to be of the same style.

I looked into source of `tocloft.sty` and added a new command there:

```
\newcommand{\@loptitle}{%
  \addpenalty\@secpenalty
  \if@cfthaschapter
    \vspace*{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}
  \else
    \vspace{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}
  \fi
  \@cftpagestyle
  {\interlinepenalty\@M
  {\cftloftitlefont\listproblemname}{\cftafterloftitle}
  \cftmarklof
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip \cftafterloftitleskip
  \@afterheading}}
```

(based on `\@cftmakeloftitle`) It doesn't work -- during compilation I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.45 \loptitle
```

I'm sure I have `\usepackage{tocloft}` before I call `\loptitle`.

I guess my mistake is that it's not enough to `usepackage` to load it all.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I managed to get it with:

```
\vspace*{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}
{\cftloftitlefont\listproblemname\cftafterloftitle}
{\vskip\cftafterloftitleskip}
```

Still the question is interesting.